# Removing a featured image filter from a third party plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-admin

The following is output by a third party plugin, to modify the features image on posts.

```
function my_update_featured_image( $html, $post_id, $attachment_id ) {
    return customgeneratedimg( $html, 'post_thumbnail_html', $attachment_id );
}
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'my_update_featured_image', 10, 3 );
```

I've tried adding the following in order to remove it, but it's not working, with no change the third party plugins featured image modifications. The below was added to my themes functions.php file.
`remove_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'my_update_featured_image', 10, 3 );`

As it's a features image on upload maybe I should call it early. Any thoughts on how to address this?
Notes:

- the function above is not part of a class
- the function above modifys the file format of a featured image after uploading